# NavigationToolbar2QT switching line colors when adding a title to plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am trying to build a GUI in pyqt5 that loads a data file, then using a dropdown menu the user can select the data to plot.

Since I am new to pyqt5 I followed the example given here:
[Display a graph on selecting a combobox option on PyQt GUI , over an existing mainwindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60630209/display-a-graph-on-selecting-a-combobox-option-on-pyqt-gui-over-an-existing-ma)

Then I added the NavigationToolbar2QT to give the user the capability to modify the curves and plot, e.g: Include a title, change line colors, modify x/y axis labels, modify legends, etc.

However, for a 60,000 lines file when I plot 3 lines and add a **new title to the plot or change the marker**, all lines switch colors unexpectedly and the plot is updated giving the wrong information because the legends remain the same. Let me indicate that I don't do anything manually to update the line colors as that isn't my intention. As an example:
When I open the file and plot 3 lines for the first time, such that:

- A vs time is blue - bottom line - legend: "line A"
- B vs time is orange - middle line - legend: "line B"
- C vs time is green - top line - legend: "line C"

If I then proceed to add a new title to the plot, using the toolbar, then:

- A vs time is green - bottom line - legend: "line C"
- B vs time is blue - middle line - legend: "line A"
- C vs time is orange - top line - legend: "line B"

Is there a better way to plot lines with  pyqt5 and also have the capability to modify the plot title and the line markers? Why is this happening? .

The code is below: (EDITED)

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo.addItem("Choose a field")
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Read csv file')

        # axes and widget for plotting and displaying the figure
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.figure_widget = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.figure_widget,self)        
        plt.tight_layout()

        # set up layout
        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hlayout.addWidget(self.combo)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.button)
        hlayout.addStretch(2)
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.toolbar)        
        vlayout.addWidget(self.figure_widget)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.read_data)
        self.combo.currentTextChanged.connect(self.field_changed)

    def read_data(self):
        dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self, directory=os.curdir, caption='Open data file' )
        dialog.setAcceptMode(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.AcceptOpen)
        dialog.setFileMode(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ExistingFile)
        if dialog.exec():
            # read data and add columns to combo box
            file = dialog.selectedFiles()[0]
            self.data = pd.read_csv(file)
            self.combo.clear()
            self.combo.addItem("Choose a field")
            self.time_column_name = list(self.data.keys())[0]            
            self.time_column = self.data[self.time_column_name] 
            for field in self.data.columns:
                if field != self.time_column_name:
                    self.combo.addItem(field)
            self.combo.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def field_changed(self, field):
        self.ax.clear()
        if field in self.data.columns:
            self.data.plot(x=self.time_column_name,y=field, ax=self.ax)
            self.ax.set_ylabel(field)
            self.ax.set_xlabel('index')
        plt.tight_layout()
        self.fig.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

### Example data file format:

1 time A B C

2 0.000025 32.0789999 45.0986766 74.054567433

3 0.000050 33.0548333 47.2343400 76.038787222

4

.

.

.

.

.

Comment: Can you provide a simple and short sample of the data you're reading, so that we could better understand how your code works?

Comment: It's a multiple column tab separated file. I am editing my post, to include an example. The code uses a button that opens a file and then loads it and makes it a data frame. Then plots the data depending on the "field" chosen from the drop-down menu.